# Deploy django project, warnings in imports

Tags: python, django, deployment, python-imaging-library

i try to deploy my app and try to use

> gunicorn sprutlabs.wsgi

, and after i get

```
 File "/root/studsovietshow3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 67, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

I have already installed Pillow

Comment: You're probably missing the system-level dependencies - `libjpeg` in particular. See the [documentation on how to install these](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/installation.html#building-on-linux).